# how to let this result display in columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have two tables in a oracle DB.
Table t1:

```
Account    name
  001       peter 
  002      george
```

Table t2:

```
Account payday  amount
  001    190129    100
  001    190128     80
  001    190201     60
  002    190125     50
```

Now I want to get result like:

```
Account name   payday amount payday amount payday amount
001     Peter  190129   100  190128  80    190201   60
002     george 190125   50
```

I can use following SQL if I know how many times of payments at most for one account.

```
  SELECT t1.account,
       t1.name,
       pay1.payday,
       pay1.amount,
       pay2.payday,
       pay2.amount,
       pay3.payday,
       pay3.amount
FROM t1 left
JOIN (
     SELECT account,
            payday,
            amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY account
                 ORDER BY account
            ) AS rowcounts
     FROM t2
) pay1 ON ( t1.account = pay1.account AND pay1.rowcounts = 1 )
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT account,
            payday,
            amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY account
                 ORDER BY account
            ) AS rowcounts
     FROM t2
) pay2 ON ( t1.account = pay2.account AND pay2.rowcounts = 2 )
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT account,
            payday,
            amount,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                 PARTITION BY account
                 ORDER BY account
            ) AS rowcounts
     FROM t2
) pay3 ON ( t1.account = pay3.account AND pay3.rowcounts = 3 )
```

But if I don't know maxim payment times can I get above result using SQL? Thx.

Comment: I think you are looking for dynamic Pivot. Refer past answers for the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D%3Adynamic+pivot

Comment: looks like oracle doesn't support dynamic SQL